# Data repeat on each cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

---

Hi! I have a problem on `UITableView`. I add `PickerView` to my `textField` in some of row in section as code below. Actually, `pickerView` will add to cell at indexPath.row but not for each section. So that make me stuck for this morning. Sorry my english isn't good. Special thank for your solution.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = (self.tableItems[indexPath.section].value?[indexPath.row])!
    let identifier : String = data["CELL_IDENTIFIER"]!!
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
    if cell is QuotationHeaderInSectionCell{
        let headerCell = cell as! QuotationHeaderInSectionCell
        headerCell.lblHeaderInSectionTitle.text = data["TEXT_LABEL"]!!
    }else if cell is QuotationItemCell{
        let itemCell = cell as! QuotationItemCell
        itemCell.lblCellTitle.text = data["TEXT_LABEL"]!!
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 1:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: titlePickerView)
                break
            case 4:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: genderPickerView)
                break
            case 10:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: provincePickerView)
                break
            case 11:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: districtPickerView)
                break
            case 12:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: communePickerView)
                break
            case 13:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: villagePickerView)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        case 1:
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: assetMakePickerView)
                break
            case 1:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: assetRangePickerView)
                break
            case 2:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: assetModelPickerView)
                break
            case 3:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: assetColorPickerView)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        case 2:
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: dealerPickerView)
            }
            break
        case 3:
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: financeProductPickerView)
                break
            case 1:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: advPaymentPercentPickerView)
                break
            case 3:
                self.initInputViewForTextField(sender: itemCell.textFieldCell, inputView: assetColorPickerView)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }else if cell is QuotationCommentCell{
        let commentCell = cell as! QuotationCommentCell
        commentCell.textViewComment.text = data["TEXT_LABEL"]!!
    }else if cell is DocumentTableViewCell{
        let documentCell = cell as! DocumentTableViewCell
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Since tableView reuses cell, you might want to consider having the picker view as part of the cell, by storyboard prototype or by the cell subclass init. Then optionally showing it only on cells that are suppose to have a picker. As for the values of the picker you can instead have each set in an array as constant of either this view controller or a global const. That way you need not add and remove views for every cell appearing.

Comment: what type of array as constant? more detail plz

Answer (score 0):

After a second thought I might as well give a formal answer.

You can add textField into the prototype a cell with storyboard or init function of the cell subclass.

Then have a indexPath property in the view controller to know which picker you are populating when it appears - I usually name it currentIndexPath, pass that into the cell too.

Set delegate to the cell that owns that picker's textField. In addition, create an array in the cell subclass to hold the data for your picker.

During the cellForRowAt your codes will look something like

```
if cell is QuotationItemCell {
    let itemCell = cell as! QuotationItemCell
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1,4,10,11,12,13: 
            itemCell.textField.alpha = 1
            currentIndexPath = indexPath
            itemCell.currentIndexPath = indexPath //Property of the cell subclass
            itemCell.dataArray = dataDict[indexPath.row]
            itemCell.pickerView.reloadAllComponent //If the pickerView cannot be accessed here create a method in the cell subclass to reload it.
        default:
            itemCell.textField.alpha = 0
        }
    }
}
```

In the UIPickerDelegate method titleForRow can just read from the cell's array.

The array you are asking might actually be better as a dictionary

```
class yourViewController, UIViewController {
    let dataDict = [4:["Male","Female"],
                   10:["Something","Else"]] //Make sure the key correspond to the row the data is in
    var currentIndexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath() //This is suppose to be here too

}
```

Comment: pickerView isn't in QUotationItemCell

Comment: I add to textField, so that when i focus on textfield it load pickerView

Comment: Give me a moment, I'll try adjust it for that use